# How to prevent webpack DefinePlugin from changing vendor bundle file name?

Tags: caching, webpack

I have followed webpack [caching guide](https://webpack.js.org/guides/caching/) and now I have 3 bundles: main, runtime, and vendors.

However, in my webpack.config.js, I use [DefinePlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/) to export package.json `version` to the UI, like so:

```js
new DefinePlugin({
  'process.env': {
    VERSION: JSON.stringify(`v${packageJSON.version}`)
   }
}),
```

This causes my vendor bundle file name to change with each release of the UI.

How can I put the globals defined with DefinePlugin into the main bundle?

Answer (score 0):

Turned out the problem is with the key defined with DefinePlugin: `'process.env'`.

We missed to read plugin [warning box](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/), so webpack was replacing every occurrence of `process.env` in third-party libraries with our object. As we also include the app version, the resulting `vendors.*.js` bundle were different for each release.

By renaming `process.env` to just `env` (and changing our code accordingly), webpack is now able to produce the same `vendors.*.js` bundle, regardless of our app version.